# JIRA: how to create filter with order by active sprint tasks order

Tags: jira, jql

I'd like to create a filter in JIRA to be used in my Dashboard, that will display a list of tasks from current sprint - and add ORDER BY the sorting I've done in the sprint by dragging tasks (from top to bottom).

I wrote this JQL:

```
project = Project_name AND issuetype in (standardIssueTypes(), subTaskIssueTypes()) AND sprint in openSprints()
```

But I don't know what param to put with ORDER BY

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

JIRA manages the order in sprint using a "hidden" field called 'Rank'. So you can simply add to your filter:

```
order by Rank ASC
```